# how can i get order number containing one item only?

Tags: mysql

For example, I have a table with multiple order number and each order number has multiple `itemnum`.  Then, each order number has same item but some order number has only one item. How can I get them?

How can I get the `ordernum` with `itemnum` 123456 only?

[image: sample table]

with `select ordernum from table where itemnum=123456`

It displays me all `ordernum` with that `itemnum` but not the `ordernum` containing only that `itemnum`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As you can see in the image, there are multiple records with the same `itemnum` so you will get multiple records.  What do you mean by "_not the ordernum containing only that itemnum_"?

Comment: on the image there was ordernum = "000002" and "000003" , the two ordernum has only one itemnum="123456"  , i only want to display those two ordernum, but with select ordernum from table where itemnum=123456 , it display me all ordernum with itemnum="123456"

Answer (score 0):

It will be solved by using SQL `HAVING` clause. `HAVING COUNT(ordernum) = 1 AND itemnum = 123456` ensures that only ordernum with a single record has itemnum 123456 Try this:

```
SELECT ordernum
FROM table
GROUP BY ordernum
HAVING COUNT(ordernum) = 1 AND itemnum = 123456;
```

Comment: Jordy, #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.teble.itemnum' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Have you try change `SELECT *`  to `SELECT ordernum`?

Comment: That or use UNIQUE might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a nested subquery like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.ordernum
FROM
    `test` AS t1,
    (SELECT t2.ordernum, COUNT(t2.ordernum) AS cnt FROM `test` AS t2 GROUP BY t2.ordernum) AS t3
WHERE
    t1.itemnum=123456
    && t1.ordernum=t3.ordernum
    && t3.cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your code does and how is answers the question? don't simply post a code.